# Animar activity de forma circular

Tags: android, animação

Eu gostaria de fazer um efeito de transição ao chamar uma activity.

Quando a imagem, nesse caso uma circular, for pressionada a activity crescesse a partir de um circulo com mesmo raio da imagem até preencher toda a tela.

Answer (score 0):

Pesquise sobre `overridePendingTransition`  tem uma questão [aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30958834/circular-reveal-transition-for-new-activity) ensinando como fazer com modo circular (que acredito ser o que você gostaria de fazer).